# How to filter response messages from ActiveMQ for subscribers in JMeter using JMS Publisher and JMS Subscriber

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I'm creating a load test where I try to sent three types of JSON messages through ActiveMQ topic to server. After sending first message I get 3 responses, sending second - get 2 responses according to business logic.
One iteration sequentially:

- publish message1
- consume 3 responses as a result of successful processing message1
- publish message2
- consume 2 responses as a result of successful processing message2
- etcetera

I need to start 50 parallel iterations and not to confuse messages from different iterations. How can I do it?
I tried JMS selector but this one can filter messages by the headers only. I don't have any specific headers for each responses to get.
Can I filter messages, for example, by UUID? And how it can be implemented? I tried to find needed info on Internet but without results.

Will be very thankful for advices and help with it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, messages can be filtered by either header (fixed set of JMS header names) or by property (custom key-value pair).

JMSCorrelationID may be a good bet here. You can publish all messages for a given producer (or iteration) w/ the same JMSCorrelationID and then check the consumer counts that way.

ie.. for producer1 set: JMSCorrelationID = 'producer-1'
for producer2 set: JMSCorrelationID = 'producer-2'

Comment: Yes, it helps. However, now I can capture only first response with JMSCorrelationID. How can I mark all responses for message sent? Thank you!

Comment: It is difficult to understand where you are stuck without sample code and/or a better understanding of the overall design. Are you able to share more details in your answer?